# Azure Web App error 500 on Connection String

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I've a simple ASP.NET Core 1.0 application which seeds some data in to SQL Server in Azure. I've 2 databases, one is for development and other is for Production (Azure SQL), I'm using Identity. When I run my application on my local machine, it works fine, but when I deploy it I get the error 500 (Internal Server Error) with no further explanation here is my code.

```
if (CurrentEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
                                                        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        }
        else if (CurrentEnvironment.IsStaging() || CurrentEnvironment.IsProduction())
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                                                        options.UseSqlServer(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SQLCONNSTR_kConnectionString")));
        }
```

If I change the environment setting from Production to Development using Azure Application Settings, it says that error is at `Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")` saying connection string cannot be null.

Comment: Do you store your connection string in a json (user secrets or appsettings.json) or in environmental variables? And what's the structure? It should look like `"ConnectionStrings": { "DefaultConnection": "..." }`. Note that this is a change to previous versions of ASP.NET Core (i.e. rc1), where it was `"Data" : { "DefaultConnection" : { "ConnectionString" : "..." }}` before

Answer (score 1):

There is a special pattern to be used, when you want to set the Variables from Environmental Variables.

In Azure App Service you set up your connection string as "DefaultConnection" or "SQLCONNSTR_kConnectionString" respectively, but you need to use. So if your connection string is "DefaultConnection", your appsetting.json must look like this

```
"ConnectionStrings" : {
    "DefaultConnection" : "..."
}
```

when you obtain it with `Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")` (alternatively you can get it via `Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]`).

If you load it from environmental variables, it's better to override the default connection string via

```
 var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(hostEnv.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostEnv.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

Then the environmental variables will automatically override your settings in the `appsettings.json` or `appsettings.Production.json`.

If you want to get it via `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` you need to make it `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionStrings__SQLCONNSTR_kConnectionString")` on Linux and `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionStrings:SQLCONNSTR_kConnectionString")` on Windows. It's on top of my head, but the convention was something similar to this

Comment: The code that you showed (That should be in `Startup.cs` constructor) I've already written, also the new way of defining connection string is the same that you showed the thing I did not try is `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionStrings:SQLCONNSTR_kConnectionString")` but I'm still getting 500 Internal Server Error after trying this. :(

Comment: Where as data is being seeded successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I might misunderstand what you meant by "Azure SQL", but if you're using hosted Azure DB, then the prefix for the environment variable will be `SQLAZURECONNSTR_` instead of `SQLCONNSTR_`.  The latter would be used, for example, if you have SQL on your own VM in Azure (IaaS).

Also, it may help you to break apart your combined line of:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                                                        options.UseSqlServer(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SQLCONNSTR_kConnectionString")));
```

into separate lines, something like the following, then you might be able to diagnose the issue a bit easier.

```
var envConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(...);

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(envConnectionString))
{
  // log error, throw exception, etc      
}
else
{
  services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
                                              options.UseSqlServer(envConnectionString)));
}
```

Comment: Replacing `SQLCONNSTR_` with `SQLAZURECONNSTR_` also did not work. :(. for the most, I also tried to pass the direct Azure SQL db connection string to `UseSqlServer()` method, but I'm still getting this 500 error. Where as the data got inserted successfully. I took a look Azure logs, event but I can't find the origin of the error.

Comment: Are you able to debug locally on your dev machine, pointed to your hosted Azure DB?  To do this,  you may need to add your IP to open the DB firewall.  Instructions here:  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-configure-firewall-settings/

Answer (score 1):

Thank for your respond, actually I resolved my issue. Since ASP.NET Core RC 2, we have to use

```
"publishOptions": {
"include": [
  "wwwroot",
  "Views",
  "Areas/**/Views",
  "appsettings.json",
  "web.config"
] },
```

options in `project.json` in order work them. :)

Comment: Also in .net core 1

Comment: Ya, you will also find this in the default VS ASPNET Core templates!